# sscanf() in C to skip over an integer and read string

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file that contains data in this form:

> 1 Jake 234 Ruby 98.

I want to use `sscanf` to read only the strings into arrays, so I tried this:

```
male[i] = malloc(100);
female[i] = malloc(100);

sscanf(str, "%*d%s%*d%s%*d", &male[i], &female[i]);
```

The problem is that when `i = 0`, the function skips the first string along with the first integer. So when I try to print `&male[0]`, I get a blank space.

I have initialised `i` to be `0`. Could someone please point out where I might be going wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this : `sscanf(str, "%*d%s%*d%s%*d", male[i], female[i]);` `printf("%s %s\n", male[i], female[i]);`

Comment: Why are you not testing the result of `sscanf()`?  You must test the to know how much of it worked, which helps identify where the problem is.  You'll never know whether the last `%*d` succeeded so it may as well be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `male[i]` rather than `&male[i]`.
2. Limit your string input by 99 (1 less than the size of the buffer space)
3. Check the return value of `sscanf()`
4. The last `"%*d"` does not do anything.

-

```
char *male[N]; // assumed sample declaration
char *female[N];

male[i] = malloc(100);
female[i] = malloc(100);
int cnt = sscanf(str, "%*d%99s%*d%99s", male[i], female[i]);
if (cnt == 2) Success();
```

If you want to insure all the data is parsed and no non-white-space at the end....

```
int n = 0;
int cnt = sscanf(str, "%*d%99s%*d%99s%*d %n", male[i], female[i], &n);
if (cnt == 2 && str[n] == '\0') Success();
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Thanks - caught that on 1 line but not 2 - now fixed.